# Python: Why doesn't .strip() work on an entire file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary, strip

So I have a large text file (a book), but I'm trying to strip the entire text file of punctuations,special chars, and white space so I can form a dictionary of all the words.  For some reason when I use the .strip() method it does practically nothing.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    entire = file.read()
    entire = entire.lower() #lower case the entire text (this works)
    entire = entire.strip(string.punctuations + string.digit) #this however does nothing
```

How do I strip the entire book of punctuations and digits so I can build a dictionary?

Comment: Because it isn't supposed to do that. Why do you think it's supposed to do that? You won't find any tutorial or documentation that claims such a thing.

Comment: Just started programming in python so its a bit foreign to me, Would like your insight on how to approach this problem!  Cheers! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO proper is not a documentation website.

Comment: `string.punctuations + string.digit` should be `string.punctuation + string.digits` (not that that line would do what you want it to do)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.translate()` to remove characters:

```
import string

table = {ord(k) : None for k in string.punctuation + string.digits}
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    entire = f.read().lower() #lower case the entire text (this works)
    entire = entire.translate(table)
```

`table` specifies the characters that you want to remove by mapping them to `None`. A dictionary comprehension is used to construct `table`. Then `str.translate()` is called to perform the removal.

Comment: I didn't know that `str.translate` works without `str.maketrans` in Python 3, thanks.

Comment: @Blender: It does, but I originally had an error: the table must map the Unicode ordinal to `None` in order to be effective. `str.maketrans()` does that, or you can use `ord()` in the dict comprehension.

Comment: That's just what `str.maketrans` does. I guess `str.translate` just ignored invalid keys.

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip` does not look beyond the ends of a string. For example:

```
>>> 'abcXYZabcXYZbca'.strip('abc')
'XYZabcXYZ'
```

You can instead build a translation table and use `str.translate` instead:

```
>>> import string
>>> table = str.maketrans({c: None for c in string.punctuation + string.digits})
>>> "Foo bar's baz, 123 abc".translate(table)
'Foo bars baz  abc'
```